# ¿Cómo copiar una columna de una hoja de excel a otra de otro libro con interop?

Tags: vb.net, interop

Para hacer una copia de los valores de una columna de una hoja de excel lo hago sin problema pero dentro del mismo libro, quiero hacer lo mismo pero ahora copiar una columna a otra hoja de otro libro diferente.

Por el momento lo hago de la siguiente manera y me marca error al hacerlo con dos libros diferentes.

```
xlSourceRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A10")
xlDestRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1")
xlSourceRange.Copy()
xlDestRange.PasteSpecial(Paste:=Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, Operation:=Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
                                 SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos Julio:

He probado el trozo de código que indicas y a mi me copia sin problemas de un libro al otro, a lo mejor si pegaras el código completo podríamos ayudarte mejor. Yo te pasteo el código que he probado y que me ha funcionado por si te sirve de algo.

```
    Public Sub copiaCeldas()
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True
    Try

        Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\source.xlsx")
        Dim xlSource As Excel.Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("test")

        Dim workbook2 As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\destino.xlsx")
        Dim xldest As Excel.Worksheet = workbook2.Worksheets("test")

        Dim xlSourceRange As Excel.Range = xlSource.Range("A1:A10")
        Dim xlDestRange As Excel.Range = xldest.Range("A1")
        xlSourceRange.Copy()
        xlDestRange.PasteSpecial(Paste:=Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, Operation:=Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
                             SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
        workbook2.Save()
        workbook.Close()
        workbook2.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    app.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta @Otxoto, haré la prueba y en un rato mas agrego el código completo.

Comment: Me he percatado que mi código deja de funcionar después de correr mi proyecto unas 4 veces seguidas, me genera un error en las lineas mencionadas que puse anteriormente. Para resolverlo cierro visual studio y vuelvo abrirlo, después de hacer esto me hace el copiado sin problema, pero no se por que pase esa situación.